# How to extract the angles in facial features that will be used for facial expression recognition

Tags: opencv, expression, image-recognition, contour

I am using Visual Studio 2010 C++ and OpencV 2.1. I used haar cascade classifiers to detect the [features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aF18.jpg) in the face (mouth, eyes, eyebrows).

But I'm really a newbie so i was not able to make much progress. I want to extract the [angles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Dyx.jpg) to calculate for the facial expression of the image. I think it has to deal with contour points, (Active Contour Model or "snakes"), etc.

I'm having a hard time to detect the facial expression of an image. Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Could you post some pictures or a link showing the difference in expressions you'd like to detect? If you start by detecting only extreme changes, then you might try a relatively simple technique first. It can help to develop some familiarity with simpler solutions before trying to solve the more general problem of detecting subtle differences in facial expressions.

Comment: I already posted the images (links -- since i can't post any pic here yet with less than 10 reputation) @Rethunk. What do you think about it? Thanks again if you have more suggestions :)